# Geolocation not working on Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation

When using Android Studio's Android emulator, Geolocation does not work. I tried every solution posted here on SO, but nothing seems to work. The code is just fine, since it works flawlessy on my actual device. This is the HTML-page I am using:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("locationHolder").innerHTML = latlon;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log("Location information is unavailable");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
           console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>

<div id="locationHolder">No location</div>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get position</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the webview:

```
public void openWebView(){
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); 
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.html");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.toString());
                return true;
            }


        });



    }
```

And this is the output of the log:

```
05-20 08:09:23.442 28860-29006/com.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30184 of [00bb9c9ce4]
05-20 08:09:23.442 28860-28881/com.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30184 of [00bb9c9ce4]
05-20 08:09:23.442 28860-28881/com.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30184: (2) open(/GeolocationPermissions.db) - 
05-20 08:09:23.442 28860-29006/com.app E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30184: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
05-20 08:09:23.452 28860-28860/com.app I/Web Console: Location information is unavailable at file:///android_asset/www/test.html:26
```

This problem occurs with Nexus 4 API 18, but also with other emulators I've tried. I've chosen for these emulators for the Google API.

Comment: Have you tried in a real device? I dont think the emulator webview is able to access the fake GPS coordinates

Comment: @MatPag Yup, real device works just fine. It would be a shame if the emulator can't access GPS, because that's how I'm making sure the app works on all API versions. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: The emulator doesn't have a real GPS system. But the coordinates can be provided by the "Location" extended control which pass the coordinates to the framework API of the device emulating the real GPS. The problem is that you are not using the FusedLocationApi, but you are accessing the coordinates from the Javascript of the webview. I dont know if this is possible in an emulator sincerely

Comment: @MatPag Thanks, yeah I'm accessing it via Javascript/HTML5.